Uniqueness of Two Series in an Intersection
I've been working on some problems involving series and have found myself applying the identity principle to show that two representations of a series will lead them being unique under some conditions.
However in a more general setting, I haven't been able to answer this question:
Suppose I have a complex series defined on $D(0, 2)$ by
$$f(z)= \sum a_n z^n$$
and I have another series defined on $D(3,3)$ by
$$g(z)= \sum b_n (z-3)^n$$
If $g \equiv f$ on $D(0,2) \cap D(3,3)$ must all the coefficients be the same? Note that I left out the indices because I am not sure if the conclusion is different between taylor or laurent series.

what does it mean coefficients be the same? the power series are centered at different points and $3$ is not in the given domain of convergence for $f$ nor $0$ is in the given domain for $g$, so unclear what the question means; if for example, $g$ would converge on $D(3,4)$ say so $0$ is in there, then expanding $\sum b_n(z-3)^n$ in terms of $z^k$ and rearranging (which is permitted in this case) leads indeed to $a_n$
